# Show that if $G \neq \langle 1 \rangle$ is a group which has as its only subgroups $ \langle 1 \rangle$ and $G$ then $G$ is finite and of prime order

Tags: group-theory

My issue is showing G is finite. I am able to show that $G$ is cyclic by assuming $a \in G$ where $a \neq 1$ so $ \langle a \rangle$ is either $ \langle 1 \rangle$ or $G$, where by the choice of $a$ it is not $ \langle 1 \rangle$ so it must be $G$. My textbook tells me next to consider $a^2$. I know if $a^2$ = 1 then obviously $G$ is cyclic, but what do I do in the case where $a^2 \neq 1$.

Also (assuming G is finite) I know that $G$ would have to be prime. If the order of G is $n$ then for any positive integer $j$ where $j|n$ there always exists exactly one subgroup of this order. Clearly though $G$ only has two subgroups, one of order $n$ and one of order 1, hence $n$ is prime.

Comment: HINT: Look at the subgroup generated by $a^2$. If $G$ is infinite, is it all of $G$?

Comment: A follow-up to Brian's excellent comment: if $G$ is infinite, could you get the elementa $a$ from powers of $a^2$?

Comment: so if $a^2 \neq 1$ then it is a generator for $G$. Since $ \langle a^2 \rangle$ only contains $a^{2n}$,  it would not be possible for $a^2$ to be a generator if $G$ was infinite ?

Comment: Think concretely, if $G$ is infinite cyclic, it is (isomorphic to) the integers, but then the even integers (or the ones divisible by $99$) give us a proper subgroup.